# Dynamic Camera Caliberation OpenCV python3

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, camera-calibration, inverse-kinematics

I am planning on making a robotic arm. I have a camera mounted on the arm. I am using Opencv with python3 to do IP.

I want the arm to detect the point on the ground and the servos to move accordingly. I have completed the part of detection and calculating the world coordinates. Also, the inverse kinematics that is required.

The problem here is that I have calibrated the camera for a certain height (20 cm). So, the correct world coordinates are received at the height of 20 cm only. I want the camera to keep correcting the reading at every 2s that it moves towards the ground (downward).

Is there a way that I can do the calibration dynamically, and give dynamic coordinates to my arm? I don't know if this is the right approach. If there is another method to do this, please help.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using the `undistort` function to first undistort the image and then using the rotational vector(`rcvt`) and translational vector(`tvct`) along with `distortCoeffs` to get the world coordinates. The correct coordinates are only obtained at that specific height because the `rvct` and `tvct` will change according to the square size (of the chess-board) used for calibration.

A smart way to overcome this would be to eliminate the rotational vector and translational vector easily.

Since the camera calibration constants remain the same at any height/rotation, it can be used in this. Also, rather than calibrating it every 2 seconds (which would consume too much CPU), directly use the method below to get the values!

Let's say `(img_x, img_y)` is the image coordinate which you need to transform to world coordinate `(world_x, world_y)` and `cameraMatrix` is your camera matrix. For this method, you need to know the `distance_cam`, that is, the perpendicular distance of your object from the camera.

Using python, and opencv, use the following code :

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import inv

img_x, img_y = 20, 30 # your image coordinates go here
world_coord = np.array([[img_x], [img_y], [1]]) # create a 3x1 matrix
world_coord = inv(cameraMatrix) * world_coord # use formula cameraMatrix^(-1)*coordinates
world_coord = world_coord * distance_cam 
world_x = world_coord[0][0]
world_y = world_coord[1][1]
print(world_x, world_y)
```

At first, we may not realise that the units in the world coordinates don't matter. After multiplying by the inverse of the camera matrix you have defined the ratio x/z which is unitless. So, you can choose the `distance_cam` in any unit and the end result would be in the units of `distance_cam`, that is, if `distance_cam` was in `mm`, then `world_x, world_y` would also be in `mm`.